# Php contact mailer goes to a blank page

Tags: php, html, forms, post, phpmailer

Php form mailer goes to a blank page: http://www.commercialinsulation.com/proto/html/php/mail_form.php

I am new to this an have no idea why this is happening. I uploaded it to the server. I checked all the info that I could. Please help! Should be a simple thing for all you awesome coders.

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ALL); 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); 
ini_set('html_errors', 0); 
error_reporting(-1);


// This work is licensed under the MIT License - http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php


// OPTIONS - PLEASE CONFIGURE THESE BEFORE USE!

    $yourEmail = "test@test.com"; // the email address you wish to receive these mails through
    $yourWebsite = "http://www.test.com"; // the name of your website
    $thanksPage = ''; // URL to 'thanks for sending mail' page; leave empty to keep message on the same page 
    $maxPoints = 4; // max points a person can hit before it refuses to submit - recommend 4


// --- DO NOT EDIT BELOW HERE -----------------------

$error_msg = null;
$result = null;

function isBot() {
    $bots = array("Indy", "Blaiz", "Java", "libwww-perl", "Python", "OutfoxBot", "User-Agent", "PycURL", "AlphaServer", "T8Abot", "Syntryx", "WinHttp", "WebBandit", "nicebot");

    $isBot = false;
    foreach ($bots as $bot)
    if (strpos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], $bot) !== false)
        $isBot = true;

    if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) || $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] == " ")
        $isBot = true;

    exit("Bots not allowed.</p>");
}

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == "POST") {
    function clean($data) {
        $data = trim(stripslashes(strip_tags($data)));
        return $data;
    }

    $points = (int)0;

    $badwords = array("adult", "beastial", "bestial", "blowjob", "clit", "cum", "cunilingus", "cunillingus", "cunnilingus", "cunt", "ejaculate", "fag", "felatio", "fellatio", "fuck", "fuk", "fuks", "gangbang", "gangbanged", "gangbangs", "hotsex", "hardcode", "jism", "jiz", "orgasim", "orgasims", "orgasm", "orgasms", "phonesex", "phuk", "phuq", "porn", "pussies", "pussy", "spunk", "xxx", "viagra", "phentermine", "tramadol", "adipex", "advai", "alprazolam", "ambien", "ambian", "amoxicillin", "antivert", "blackjack", "backgammon", "texas", "holdem", "poker", "carisoprodol", "ciara", "ciprofloxacin", "debt", "dating", "porn", "link=", "voyeur");
    $exploits = array("content-type", "bcc:", "cc:", "document.cookie", "onclick", "onload", "javascript");

    foreach ($badwords as $word)
        if (strpos($_POST['comments'], $word) !== false)
            $points += 2;

    foreach ($exploits as $exploit)
        if (strpos($_POST['comments'], $exploit) !== false)
            $points += 2;

    if (strpos($_POST['comments'], "http://") !== false || strpos($_POST['comments'], "www.") !== false)
        $points += 2;
    if (isset($_POST['nojs']))
        $points += 1;
    if (preg_match("/(<.*>)/i", $_POST['comments']))
        $points += 2;
    if (strlen($_POST['name']) < 3)
        $points += 1;
    if (strlen($_POST['comments']) < 15 || strlen($_POST['comments'] > 1500))
        $points += 2;

    foreach ($_POST as $key => $value)
        $_POST[$key] = trim($value);

    if (empty($_POST['name']) || empty($_POST['email']) || empty($_POST['comments'])) {
        $error_msg .= "Name, e-mail and comments are required fields. \n";
    } elseif (strlen($_POST['name']) > 15) {
        $error_msg .= "The name field is limited at 15 characters. Your first name or nickname will do! \n";
    } elseif (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-'\s]*$/", stripslashes($_POST['name']))) {
        $error_msg .= "The name field must not contain special characters. \n";
    } elseif (!preg_match('/^([a-z0-9])(([-a-z0-9._])*([a-z0-9]))*\@([a-z0-9])(([a-z0-9-])*([a-z0-9]))+' . '(\.([a-z0-9])([-a-z0-9_-])?([a-z0-9])+)+$/i', strtolower($_POST['email']))) {
        $error_msg .= "That is not a valid e-mail address. \n";
    } elseif (!empty($_POST['url']) && !preg_match('/^(http|https):\/\/(([A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)(\.[A-Z0-9][A-Z0-9_-]*)+)(:(\d+))?\/?/i', $_POST['url']))
        $error_msg .= "Invalid website url.";

    if ($error_msg == NULL && $points <= $maxPoints) {
        $subject = "Automatic Form Email";

        $message = "You received this e-mail message through your website: \n\n";
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) {
            $message .= ucwords($key) . ": " . clean($val) . "\r\n";
        }
        $message .= 'IP: '.$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\r\n";
        $message .= 'Browser: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']."\r\n";
        $message .= 'Points: '.$points;

        if (strstr($_SERVER['SERVER_SOFTWARE'], "Win")) {
            $headers   = "From: $yourEmail \r\n";
            $headers  .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}";
        } else {
            $headers   = "From: $yourWebsite <$yourEmail> \r\n";
            $headers  .= "Reply-To: {$_POST['email']}";
        }

        if (mail($yourEmail,$subject,$message,$headers)) {
            if (!empty($thanksPage)) {
                header("Location: $thanksPage");
                exit;
            } else {
                $result = 'Your mail was successfully sent.';
            }
        } else {
            $error_msg = 'Your mail could not be sent this time.';
        }
    } else {
        if (empty($error_msg))
            $error_msg = 'Your mail looks too much like spam, and could not be sent this time. ['.$points.']';
    }
}
function get_data($var) {
    if (isset($_POST[$var]))
        echo htmlspecialchars($_POST[$var]);
}
?>
```

HTML:

```
  <form class="required-form" action="php/mail_form.php" method="post">
  <ol class="forms">
      <li>
          <label for="name">Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
      </li>
      <li>
       <label for="email"><em class="required">*</em> Your Email</label>
       <input type="text" name="email" id="email" class="required" />
   </li>

   <li><label for="message">Message</label>   
       <textarea name="message" id="message"></textarea></li>
       <li class="buttons submit">
        <button type="submit">Send Message</button></li>
    </ol>
</form>
```

Comment: Do you receive any errors on your browser console or server console?

Comment: Far as I can tell, there's no value for `$thanksPage` and don't see where you're using the `get_data()` method nor where `$error_msg` is echo'd.

Comment: I receive no error messages at all, it stalls looking for http://www.commercialinsulation.com/proto/html/php/mail_form.php .

Comment: I downloaded this form, and was following the instructions for the thanks page that says "leave empty to keep message on the same page", because I would like the submit action to 1) email the info, and 2) land back on the same Contact page with a message that says something like "Thank you for your submission".

Answer (score 1):

You have set the action for your form to a specific file, while you want to stay on the same page.

Adjust your code like this so the page reloads on submit and can then perform its magic.

```
<form class="required-form" action="" method="post">
```

Comment: Or you can change it to "/proto/html/php/mail_form.php".  It's also blank because you're not POSTing when hitting the URL. It's a GET, which you don't handle in the PHP file.

Comment: @RST,, thank you for your reply. If I change the action to <form class="required-form" action="" method="post">, it lands back on the contact.html (thanks!) but with no Thank you for your submission message. If I use "/proto/html/php/mail_form.php" it is still hanging up.  AND in either case I have not received the test emails.

Comment: I assumed you included the php code at the top of the HTML, or visa versa.

Comment: I have included all the code I am using in the post above except the css. What additional php code do I need to include in my html, and where? Also, can I put all of the above code onto one page called contact.php, and will that solve my problem?

Comment: I added this line <?php include('php/mail_form.php'); ?>  but it did not make a difference...still hangs up at  http://www.commercialinsulation.com/proto/html/php/mail_form.php

Comment: save your html as .php then add at the top something like `<?php if ( isset($_POST)) { print_r($_POST); } ?>` at the top. Once that works start building upon that.